# deleting smart pointer, but still could able to access the pointee?

Tags: c++

I have returned the pointee type from  operator T*(), and invoked delete operator over smart pointer, and tried invoking the member function, and i have not got any run time error. How is that possible?  Or is my understanding is wrong? Kindly suggest.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class sPtr
{
    private:
       T * pointee__;
     public:

        operator T * () {
                cout <<"Inside T* () "<<endl;
                return pointee__;
        };
    explicit sPtr ( T * t )
    {

      pointee__ = t;
    };
    T * operator->() {
        return pointee__;
     }
};

class JTest
{
 private:
        int x;
 public:
   JTest ( int l=100) { x=l; };
    void display ();
};

void JTest::display()
{
  cout <<"Display API x is "<<x<<endl;
}

void JFunc (JTest * tmp)
{
  cout <<" JFunc"<<endl;
  tmp->display ();
  cout <<"Invoking JTest -> display "<<endl;
}


int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
 sPtr <JTest> t(new JTest);
 t->display();
 delete t; // Invokes operator T* () , and it is dangerous!!!..
t->display  ();

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Display API x is 100
Inside T* () 
Display API x is 100
```

Comment: [Stop stealing hotel room keys!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/46642)

Comment: If your question is: "Why doesn't UB crash on me every time I invoke it", then the answer is: "Because its UB"

Comment: You're doing something you're not allowed to do. There's no point asking about what to expect.

Comment: The sign said the speed limit was 30 mph. I tried, and I could go over 60 mph. How is that possible? I was expecting to get arrested.

Comment: If it were to crash *every* time you invoke and undefined behavior, it would have been *defined* behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure that program will produce the output shown.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I am a less experience in c++ and learning now. If you kindly explain me the reason why it is being closed, it could be helpful for me in feature not to ask such questions in stackoverflow.com. I even did not know that "You're doing something you're not allowed to do' as per your suggestion. Is this forum  not for the freshers?.

Comment: @Whoami: I think you're generally expected to a) know a bit about how this site works (e.g. *StackOverflow is not a forum*, and "your question has to be useful for *others*"), b) do some research of your own (this point has been discussed *so many* times already), and know the basics of your programming language. It is definitely *not* a tutorial site, or maybe "for the freshers" as you put it. It's OK to be inexperienced, but you have to make an effort. This question is probably closed because there are now useful links to better questions. No hard feelings :-)

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question; it is clear and specific.  The questioner saw unexpected behaviour and asked for an explanation.  I would not have closed it, especially not for the reason stated.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting t marks the memory pointed to by t as unused, but leaves the address stored in t intact.  When you try to use the object stored at t, C++ does not check if it has been deleted, so while what you have will often crash, it may occasionally work if the memory used by the deleted object has not yet been overwritten by the system.

In short: sometimes this will work, often it will crash, and it is always a bad idea.

If you want to protect yourself from yourself, set t to NULL after you have deleted it.

Comment: The best way to protect yourself from yourself is to not leave any deleted pointers exposed, i.e., make all uses of `delete` be with private data members and always inside destructors. Or better, forget about `delete` and follow the [rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html). (IOW, if you have a concierge for each customer that always opens their room for them, people cannot steal hotel room keys)

Comment: Thanks Martinho. YOu helped with information, rather... ;).